# Probability that the Hubble space telescope hit by Meteoroids

Tags: space, telescopes, instrument, meteorites

What if Hubble Space Telescope or International Space State hit by micrometeoroid or meteoroid? Asking because these objects are moving at a very high velocity. [image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: You can calculate the probability based on the number of impacts in the past. See e.g. https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2014/pdf/1722.pdf

Comment: Also related: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100025563.pdf